# Changed developer account and now can't log in to it from Xcode

Tags: xcode, developer-program

I was forced to changed my account name from a nickname to an email address. Now I can't log in to my developer account from Xcode. There appears to be no way to just edit the current developer ID in Xcode. I can add a new address, but it requires an iCloud address, which my new email is not. What can I do here to resolve this? Also, how do I ensure all my entitlements are moved to the new account?

Answer (score 1):

Silly me. I was having trouble adding my new account in Xcode. Once I did that, all was well.